# command to list logical volume I/O statistics on AIX

Tags: lvm, performance, aix, io

I am looking for a command which displays the I/O statistics of logical volumes (like reads/sec , writes/sec, io utilization %, read kb per second, written kb per second) .

I tried `iostat`, but its giving results for the whole disk.

`df` lists the volumes `/dev/hd3`, `/dev/hd4` etc. I am looking for the stats for all the entries in that format.

Below is the output of `df -k`:

```
$ df -k
    Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on  
    /dev/hd4           262144     61200   77%    10305    41% /  
    /dev/hd2          2818048    813264   72%    43118    19% /usr  
    /dev/hd9var        458752    161356   65%     6140    14% /var  
    /dev/hd3           196608    194396    2%       55     1% /tmp  
    /dev/hd1            65536     65120    1%       20     1% /home
```

Can you please point me to the right command?

Comment: Don't have an AIX system in front of me, does `iostat -F` or `iostat -f` list by filesystem (which may be enough for you, there's a one-to-one LV / FS mapping on AIX if you're not using anything odd).

Comment: Or there's an `lvmstat` command on later versions of AIX, but you need to enable collection on a per-LV basis.  `man lvmstat` should explain how.

Comment: I think you can find similar stats in nmon as well.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As EightBitTony pointed out, you're looking for the lvmstat (reference: [AIX 7.1](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.performance/lvm_perf_mon_lvmstat.htm) or [AIX 6.1](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.performance/lvm_perf_mon_lvmstat.htm) -- same syntax) command. You can enable statistics collection on an LV level or the whole VG level with `lvmstat -l LVNAME -e` (LV-level) or `lvmstat -v VGNAME -e` (VG-level). Enabling it at the VG level turns on collection for all of the LVs in the VG. You can then gather the stats you want with, for exampe, `lvmstat -l hd3 5`, to show stats for /tmp every 5 seconds. To disable the collection, use `lvmstat -l LVNAME -d` (LV-level) or `lvmstat -v VGNAME -d` (VG-level).

Answer (score 1):

For iostat, you might want to consider using the -b flag to get block device utilisation measurements, but this has to be enabled first.
For that see the [IBM AIX Version 7.1 Differences Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247910.html?Open) in section 6.4 - Enhancement of the iostat command:

> The raso command is used to turn the statistic collection on and off.
>   Example 6-47 shows how to use the raso command to turn on the
>   statistic collection that the iostat command uses.
>
> **Example 6-47** Using the raso command to turn on statistic collection
>
> ```
> # raso -o biostat=1
>  Setting biostat to 1
> ```

---

If you need a good overview, consider running a trace using the [`filemon` command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/filemon.htm) The report it generates contains statistics on a LV level, PV level, FS level and also VMM level. It will also show "hot spots" meaning busy jfs logs, overly busy disks, LV's or VG's.

For some more examples, see e.g.

- [Detailed I/O analysis with the filemon command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.performance/detailed_io_analysis_fielmon.htm)
  or
- [How to use filemon to find origin of IO](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/How%20to%20use%20filemon%20to%20find%20origin%20of%20IO)

Although you need to keep in mind that this runs a trace, so it can use considerable amounts of CPU usage for a really busy system, and you shouldn't leave it running over longer time periods.